# How to convert Javascript Array to array of functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I had a question in my interview where they asked me to transform an array to array of functions like below:

```
var a = ["a", 24, { foo: "bar" }];
var b = transform(a);

console.log(a[1]); // 24
console.log(b[1]()); // 24
```

I tried many combinations but I couldn't really do what they ask. Can someone tell me how to implement the transform function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about their intention, but a simple approach to provide the given results would be as follows:

```
function transform(a){
  return a.map( (el) => () => el );
}
```

PS: the interesting follow up question would then be about the differences between the results for `b[0]()` and `b[1]()` compared to `b[2]()` and how to mitigate the problems that might arise for the later.

Answer (score 4):

The desired behavior is a bit weird but you can do as follow:

```
const transform = arr => arr.map(elmt => () => elmt)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nice feature here, Proxy...

```
var arr = ["a", 24, { foo: "bar" }];

function transform(arr){

    return new Proxy(arr, {
        get: (obj, prop) => { return ()=>obj[prop] }
     });
}

var newArr = transform(arr);
newArr[0]();
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to call `Array.prototype.map` method on your original array `a` - the `map` method will return a new array. Each index of the new array will have get a value of an anonymous function definition that, when called, will return the value of the corresponding index in the original array.

```js
var a = ["a", 24, {
  foo: "bar"
}];
var b = transform(a);

console.log(a[1]); // 24
console.log(b[1]()); // 24

function transform(array) {
  return array.map(function(el) {
    return function() {
      return el;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!